# Xcode: Why doesn't my app save the UITextField?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uitextfield, nsuserdefaults

I have an app where I switch to a view with a TableView using presentModalViewController. The View with the TableView is however not at UITableViewController but a regular UIViewController. I have written UITextFields into the UITableViewCells. I use this action to save what the user inputs:

```
- (IBAction)saveTextField:(id)sender {

NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:TextField.text forKey:@"keyTextField"];
[userDefaults synchronize]; }
```

I call this method with this code:

```
    [TextField addTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
```

When I dismiss the ViewController using dismissModalViewController and then when I presents it again I call the NSUserDefaults in the ViewDidLoad with this code:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
TextField.text = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"keyTextField"];
```

Problem is that it doesn't work. And I can't figure out the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: try to put breakpoint in your 'savetextfield' method. Check whether the method is being called or not.. Then, post the result here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with: thanks to all of you for your effort and time :)

Turns out the problem wasn't with the code that saves and loads it. The problem was that I only created one UITextfield which I then put into every UITableViewCell and that was the problem. So I created individual UITextFields for every UITableViewCells and that fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

The `target` has to be the same as your method, meaning that if you have `- (void)saveTextField:(id)sender` then you code to add the target need to be

```
 [TextField addTarget:self action:@selector(saveTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
```

Check usin `NSLog` if your action is being run.

Comment: oh actually it already is... I just posted the wrong code... so the problem is still there :(

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting a target, can't you do that saving with the textFieldDidEndEditing: delegate method?

Answer (score 1):

use this code in view did load 
   NSUserDefaults *user=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    TextField.text=[user stringForKey:@"keyTextField"];